# Is there a function in PBI like sumif in Excel?

Tags: string, sumifs

I have more RFID for one client. In Excel I used sumif: =IF(SUMIF(Y:Y;Y155;N:N)>100000;"A";"N"). I have more RFID assigned to one client, but its assigned after specific date. I need a formula in PBI which search if this client has a RFID assigned anytime put A, else put N.
Ex: One RFID was read in 01.09, 02.09, 03.09, 04.09 etc. But RFID was assigned to a client in 03.09. I need to put A to RFID.

I tried use sumx in PBi but RFID is string type